# Terraform 'for in' to flatten nested map structure

Tags: terraform

I have some terraform code for managing our gitlab sub groups in a nested fashion. The output I get is something like below, in the locals, and would like to flatten it. All the key names are unique and at each sub_group level there may be 1 or more maps.

Essentially I have something like this:

```
locals {
  groups = {
    group1 = {
      id = 1
      sub_group_1 = {
        group2 = {
          id = 2
        }
        group3 = {
          id = 3
          sub_group_2 = {
            group4 = {
              id = 4
              sub_group_3 = {
                group5 = {
                  id = 5
                  sub_group_4 = {
                    group6 = {
                      id = 6
                      sub_group_5 = {
                        group7 = {
                          id = 7
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still struggling to get the `for in` method when nested. This is what i have so far but it doesn't work.

```
output "Test" {
  value = {
    for k1, v1 in local.test.groups : {
      for k2, v2 in v1.sub_group_1 : {
        for k3, v3 in v2.sub_group_2 : {
          for k4, v4 in v3.sub_group_3 : {
            for k5, v5 in v4.sub_group_4 : {
              for k6, v6 in v5.sub_group_5 : {
                k6 => v6.id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to get it to look like this:

```
groups = {
  group1 = 1
  group2 = 2
  group3 = 3
  group4 = 4
  group5 = 5
  group6 = 6
  group7 = 7
}
```

Then It'd make it easy for me to add gitlab projects and have user pass in group_name and I can pull the ID needed for the gitlab_project resource.

Currently we have 2 step process where group is created, then user manually get's ID from gitlab site and configures projects with the group ID.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Missing key/value separator 

on main.tf line 63, in output "Test":
62:               for k6, v6 in v5["sub_group_5"] : {
63:                 k6 => v6

Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Also your `locals` is an invalid TF code, so probably that's why it won't even run.

Comment: Sorry I had an `=` in the locals declaration. Edited to fix.

Comment: @Marcin I updated the original post with the error.